# How to select distinct rows for avg aggragate function in mysql when using joins?

Tags: mysql, join

[image]

[image]

**Query** : Calculate the difference between average salary of pilots and average salary of employees(including pilots). 
**pilots are those employees whose eid appears in certified tabel**

**Query I wrote :**

```
select (select avg(salary) from 
employee join certified using (eid))-(select avg(salary) from employee) as Difference;
```

But it gives wrong result , I think it is calculting average by using every entry in certified table.( eid 10 appears 4 times in certified , so it is using salary of employee with eid 10 four times) , i need to calculate average only for distinct eid in certified table.

how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select (select avg(salary) 
        from employee 
        where eid in (select eid from certified)) 
       - (select avg(salary) from employee) as Difference;
```

or with a join:

```
select (select avg(salary) 
        from employee 
        join (select distinct eid from certified) as t
        using (eid)) 
       - (select avg(salary) from employee) as Difference;
```

Comment: Thank you very much  , @Giorgos Betsos